# Find a standard normal probability

Tags: statistics

Given a standard normal distribution, find the area under the curve that lies to the left of $z=1.43$. It would make sense to me that I need to find $P(z<1.43$). Using a table that gives values only to the hundredths place, do I need to find the probability of $z \leq 1.43$ or the probability of $z\leq 1.42$ since I am supposed to find it strictly less than $1.43$ ?

Comment: Well, the normal distribution is continuous, so $P(z < 1.43) = P(z \le 1.43)$. I would use the 1.43 value.

Comment: Then suppose I need to find P(z=.5). Would I solve this by finding P(z≤.5)-P(z≤.49)?

Comment: No, the probability of hitting an exact number is zero. One way to see this is that you must have $P(z=0.5) \le P(0.5 -\epsilon < z < 0.5 +\epsilon) = P(z < 0.5+\epsilon) - P(z < 0.5 -\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon>0$, so continuity shows that $P(z=0.5) = 0$.

Comment: Why is that true?

Comment: See my edited comment...

Comment: Would it be true that for a standard normal distribution, the probability that an event occurs is an area and so an exact number would have no area?

Comment: The question is about a standard normal distribution, right? If the cdf. is continuous (as it is here), the probability of a exact number occurring is zero, for the same reason described above.

Answer (score -1):

$P(z < 1.43) = 0.9236$, and $P(z < 1.42) = 0.9222$. So the difference is at the thousandth place value, and they are different values of $z$. Since $z$ is a continuous variable, $P(z = 0.5) = 0$ for example.